# Using VK Authentication in Identity Server 4

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4, vk

I need to create service in **ASP.NET Core** application, which implements for login by **VK authorization server**. Maybe it is possible with the help of **Identity Server 4**? I know, that it has Facebook, Google authentication. How to implement VK authentication with the help of Identity Server 4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same way you do it for Google for example ([read here](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/release/quickstarts/4_external_authentication.html)).

You need to create an app in VK, and then add this app as an External provider to your IdentityServer.

The link that I provide is step 4 of the IdentityServer setup, but I strongly recommend you to start from the very beginning.

Comment: When I read this info, I find library in GitHub [link](https://github.com/aspnet-contrib/AspNet.Security.OAuth.Providers). It contains extension method for VK. Thanks!